# R - Efficiently calculating the time elapsed between records based on condition

Tags: r, execution-time

I have a dataset made up of monitor readings for a location tracking system. Unfortunately, I'm not skilled enough to replicate it randomly, so here are the first few records:

```
  Time               TagID   MonitorID  Location
2017-10-31 23:03:26 1427435   1352303    A4.18
2017-10-31 23:06:02 1427435   1352303    A4.18
2017-10-31 23:06:20 1427435   1352303    A4.18
2017-10-31 23:06:50 1427435   1352303    A4.18
2017-10-31 23:06:51 1427435   1352303    A4.18
2017-10-31 23:07:20 1427435   1352303    A4.18
                      .
                      .
                      .
2017-11-22 22:29:55 1427435   1349044    B6.24
2017-11-22 22:30:22 1427435    286748    B6.41
2017-11-22 22:30:25 1427435   1349044    B6.24
2017-11-22 22:30:40 1427435    286748    B6.41
2017-11-22 22:30:41 1427435    286748    B6.41
2017-11-22 22:30:55 1427435   1349044    B6.24
```

I'm trying to determine the time that a RFID tag has spent in a particular monitor location, by looking at how much time passed before the MonitorID reading changes. I do this via this function that I wrote:

```
elapsed_time <- function(x) {
  # Prepare variables
  current_monitor <- x$MonitorID[1]
  start_time <- x$Time[1]
  end_time <- NULL
  output <- data.frame("Date" = as.POSIXct(as.character()), "MonitorID" = as.integer(), 
                      "Minutes_elapsed" = as.integer())
  # For loop to iterate over rows
  for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    # if the new monitor is the same as the old one then go to next iteration
    # otherwise calculate the time between dates, add values to output
    if (x$MonitorID[i] == current_monitor & i != nrow(x)) {
      next
    } else {
      # Mark what the time is when the location changes
      end_time <- x$Time[i]
      # Calculate time difference
      time_spent <- difftime(end_time, start_time, units = "mins")
      # Create temporary data frame to append to output
      temp <- data.frame(start_time, current_monitor, time_spent)
      # Append temp to output
      output <- rbind(output, setNames(temp, names(output)))
      # Set the new start time to the current time
      start_time <- end_time
      # Set the current monitor tracker to the new monitor
      current_monitor <- x$MonitorID[i]
    }
  }
  # Add monitor mappings to output
  output <- left_join(output, Mmappings[,c(1,2)], by="MonitorID")
  return(output)
}
```

The last line can be ignored, it is just meant to remap the actual location name to MonitorID readings. This function works as desired, however it takes a very long time to run for just one monitor (~4 minutes) and I would like to use it with around 95 monitors at once in another function. I'm sure that there is a more efficient way of writing this function to reduce the time taken.

EDIT: Here is some example output as requested:

```
  Date                MonitorID Minutes_elapsed   Location
1 2017-10-31 23:03:26   1352303 3.36666667 mins    A4.18
2 2017-10-31 23:06:48         0 0.03333333 mins    A4.20
3 2017-10-31 23:06:50   1352303 0.45000000 mins    A4.18
4 2017-10-31 23:07:17         0 0.05000000 mins    A4.20
5 2017-10-31 23:07:20   1352303 0.45000000 mins    A4.18
6 2017-10-31 23:07:47         0 0.05000000 mins    A4.20
```

In this case the time taken between changes is short since sometimes the readings bounce to other monitors, but that is not relevant.

Comment: Not sure what we are trying to do, please provide expected output for your example input. I am guessing no need to loop over rows, maybe see `lead/lag` functions?

Comment: Could you perhaps post a bit more data with examples of the TagID and MonitorID changing as well as the required output that this data would make?

Comment: I've provided some example output and a bit more input. The data skips because there are a lot of NAs in the data set which should not be removed.

Comment: Have a look at dput(data[1:n, ]) function.

Comment: @Christoph, that's really helpful for future posts, thanks! Would I in this case copy the output of dput(data[1:20,]) into my question so people can easily replicate a sample of the dataset?

Comment: Yes, that would be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
    library(tidyverse) # for easy data manipulation
    library(lubridate) # for dealing with dates

    # create the sample data
    myDf <- frame_data(
        ~Time,               ~TagID,   ~MonitorID,  ~Location,
        "2017-10-31 23:03:26", 1427435,   1352303,    "A4.18",
        "2017-10-31 23:06:02", 1427435,   1352303,    "A4.18",
        "2017-10-31 23:06:20", 1427435,   1352303,    "A4.18",
        "2017-10-31 23:06:50", 1427435,   1352303,    "A4.18",
        "2017-10-31 23:06:51", 1427435,   1352303,    "A4.18",
        "2017-10-31 23:07:20", 1427435,   1352303,    "A4.18",
        "2017-11-22 22:29:55", 1427435,   1349044,    "B6.24",
        "2017-11-22 22:30:22", 1427435,    286748,    "B6.41",
        "2017-11-22 22:30:25", 1427435,   1349044,    "B6.24",
        "2017-11-22 22:30:40", 1427435,    286748,    "B6.41",
        "2017-11-22 22:30:41", 1427435,    286748,    "B6.41",
        "2017-11-22 22:30:55", 1427435,   1349044,    "B6.24"
    )

    # make times times
    # and (important!) sort the dataframe
    myDf <- myDf %>%
        mutate(Time = as_datetime(Time)) %>%
        arrange(TagID, Time)

    myDf %>%
        mutate(priorIDtheSame = MonitorID == lag(MonitorID)) %>%
        mutate(priorIDtheSame = replace(priorIDtheSame, is.na(priorIDtheSame), FALSE)) %>%
        mutate(nextIDtheSame = MonitorID == lead(MonitorID)) %>%
        mutate(nextIDtheSame = replace(nextIDtheSame, is.na(nextIDtheSame), FALSE)) %>%
        # we simply remove all the rows inbetween first and last at one location
        filter(!(priorIDtheSame & nextIDtheSame)) %>%
        # calculate the time difference
        mutate(timeAtThisLocation = Time - lag(Time)) %>%
        # and make sure it is only calculated were we need it
        mutate(timeAtThisLocation = replace(timeAtThisLocation, !priorIDtheSame, NA))
```

It results in

```
    # A tibble: 8 x 7
                     Time   TagID MonitorID Location priorIDtheSame nextIDtheSame timeAtThisLocation
                   <dttm>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <chr>          <lgl>         <lgl>             <time>
    1 2017-10-31 22:03:26 1427435   1352303    A4.18          FALSE          TRUE            NA secs
    2 2017-10-31 22:07:20 1427435   1352303    A4.18           TRUE         FALSE           234 secs
    3 2017-11-22 21:29:55 1427435   1349044    B6.24          FALSE         FALSE            NA secs
    4 2017-11-22 21:30:22 1427435    286748    B6.41          FALSE         FALSE            NA secs
    5 2017-11-22 21:30:25 1427435   1349044    B6.24          FALSE         FALSE            NA secs
    6 2017-11-22 21:30:40 1427435    286748    B6.41          FALSE          TRUE            NA secs
    7 2017-11-22 21:30:41 1427435    286748    B6.41           TRUE         FALSE             1 secs
    8 2017-11-22 21:30:55 1427435   1349044    B6.24          FALSE         FALSE            NA secs
```

Comment: This helped me solve it! I had to make a few changes, since the time calculation should be between the time of the first recording of a monitor and the time of the first recording of the _following_ monitor. Your way calculated the time between the first and last sightings of the _same_ monitor. I'm amazed how much faster this is. It does it in a few seconds as opposed to 4 minutes. Will read up on how dplyr functions are created to be so efficient. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Dplyr functions are so fast because (i) they use vectorization and (ii) they are partly programmed in C (or C++ - don't know exactly). Instead of figurring out why, rather invest the time to figure out how to use them. The website / book http://r4ds.had.co.nz/ by Grolemund and Wickham will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to build up an example data frame

```
df1<-data.frame(Time=c("2017-10-31 23:03:26","2017-10-31 23:06:02","2017-10-31 23:06:20","2017-10-31 23:06:50","2017-10-31 23:06:51",
                   "2017-10-31 23:07:20"),TagID=c(1427435,1427435,1427435,1427435,1427435,1427435),
           MonitorID=c(1352303,1352303,1352303,1352303,1352303,1352303),Location=c("A4.18","A4.18","A4.18","A4.18","A4.18","A4.18"))

df1$Time<-ymd_hms(df1$Time)
df2<-df1
df2$Time=df2$Time+minutes(30)
df2$MonitorID=df2$MonitorID+1
df2$Location<-"A4.19"
df<-rbind(df1,df2)
```

so if your data frame is something like the above you could calculate the time elapsed (in minutes) for every Monitor ID with the code below:

```
result<-df%>%group_by(MonitorID)%>%summarize(ElapsedTime=difftime(tail(Time,1),head(Time,1)))
```

Comment: This would be great if there was only one sighting per day, but it can be that a monitor appears again at another time. I would like to keep the different readings separate in order to be able to approximate its path throughout the day.